# Quantum theory - How a particle functions as a wave without a medium?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality, aether

I would love to understand, what does it mean that each particle also functions like a wave, after all even when sending a single particle it creates an indentation. How does a single particle in space create a disturbance if it has no medium? What exactly is it that creates the disorder?

Comment: Before going quantum, you should always start with a classical analog of the thing that bothers you, so ask yourself first how come electromagnetic wave can travel with no medium

Comment: @OfekGillon Brilliant response

Comment: Waves, that are periodical changes of medium properties, obviously need a medium. Waves, that are not periodical changes of medium properties, obviously do not need a medium

Answer (score 2):

The concept of waves comes from observations and these observations were modeled mathematically with differential wave equations.

The first waves observed , on the water , fitted well with the sine and cosine solutions of the wave equation, and energy and momentum moved over the water and the equations could predict the motion.

Then it was discovered that the wave equations gave good solutions and predictions for acoustic problems,for seismic problems. When electromagnetism was described by Maxwell with differential equations, it was discovered that light, to start with, could be modeled with the wave equations, and   electromagnetic waves could transfer energy and momentum in space without a medium.

All this is in the realm of classical physics. Particles are in the realm of quantum mechanics, and quantum mechanics was discovered because there were observations at the level of particles and molecules that classical mechanics and electromagnetism could not explain. (Atomic spectra , together with the photoelectric effect and black body radiation necessitated the introduction of a new mathematical theory that can fit the data and predict generally the behavior )

[The quantum states](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) also obey differential wave equations, whose solutions, are complex functions, $Ψ$ in the link, but the wave nature at the level of particles appears in the  $Ψ^*Ψ$ , as the **probability**  of measuring the particle at a given (x,y,z,t). At present, in [mainstream physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), there exist the elementary particles which are axiomatically assumed to be point particles, so they do not display a wave nature in (x,y,z,t).

So the answer to :

> How a particle functions as a wave without a medium

is that the particle does not function as a wave, the **probability** of measuring  it has a wave nature, the (in)famous wave-particle duality.

Now if you study the mathematics of quantum field theory, a meta mathematical level based on the simple quantum mechanical equations, you will be introduced to the concept of quantum fields, where a particle in order to be localized in space has to be in a [wavepacket form](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html),but that is another story.

> How does a single particle in space create a disturbance if it has no medium? What exactly is it that creates the disorder?

A single particle in space will not create a  disturbance , unless it interacts with another particle , real or virtual (virtual also being another story to be learned with quantum field theory).

Comment: Nice answer. (+1) Very minor point: *[...] complex functions called $\Psi$* I think *[..] often represented by $\Psi$* would be better. At the end of the day one calls it what one wants. I often use $u$, for ease of notation (in mathjax)

Comment: @Gert  thanks, I clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the physics stack exchange ABE.  You have delved into the very deep and complex subject of "fields".  Basically, fields are everywhere in space.  It is a field that allows a radio wave to travel from earth to the moon and it is a field that allows a photon to travel as a wave from the sun to the earth.  You have probably seen this photo depicting the magnetic field surrounding a magnet.
[image: Magnetic Field]

Think to yourself what could be the medium that holds this magnetic field in place, even if it was in outer space.  I think the best way for you to understand fields in just two minutes is to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BK166SL-ig) from Scientific American.  He explains is very simply and clearly.  Once you get much deeper into the quantum world, you'll come to understand that fields are EVERYTHING.  Every particle is just a ripple in the associated field.  That will get you started.